Is there any solution in regard to inaccessible forwarding URL (https) ngrok provided? I can only access http runned by laravel
my .env file:
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1

my AppServiceProvider.php:
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
 
        //   if (env(key: 'APP_ENV') === 'local' && request()->server(key: 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO') === 'https') {
        //     URL::forceScheme(scheme: 'https');
        // }

    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
 
    public function boot(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->server->has('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST')) {
            $request->server->set('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST', $request->server->get('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST'));
            $request->headers->set('X_FORWARDED_HOST', $request->server->get('HTTP_X_ORIGINAL_HOST'));
        }
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on' || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 1) || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&  $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
            $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
        }

    }
}

trusted all proxies for testing:
 $middleware->trustProxies(at: '*');

added proper handling for authorization header:
 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

screenshots:

I have tried applying all resolutions provided in stack overflow but nothing seems to be working.

You should remove all that crap from your boot method as it’s just not needed. At all. You should be using Laravel’s built-in utilities for defined trusted proxies and forwarded headers instead of trying to do it manually. Then your application will automatically detect things like whether it’s running under HTTPS, behind a proxy like ngrok, etc.

you're right. I appreciate it. The issue ight now is resolved, i just connected to another network and run the ngrok and now it's accessible. Thankyouu sir!
